# Why does the state of my laptop's battery keep switching between `Connected standby` and `Active` even though the laptop is always plugged-in?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery, power, power-management

I ran `powercfg /batteryreport` in `powershell` to view my laptop's battery report. The state of my laptop's battery keeps switching between `Connected standby` and `Active` even though  the laptop is always plugged-in and I don't close/open the lid. What could explain it?

E.g. see the table below from 2022-06-18 02:22:02:

| START TIME | STATE | SOURCE | CAPACITY | REMAINING |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-06-1709:42:18 | Connected standby | Battery | 83 % | 72,230 mWh |
| 09:42:18 | Suspended |  | 83 % | 72,230 mWh |
| 09:42:54 | Connected standby | AC | 84 % | 72,626 mWh |
| 09:43:29 | Active | AC | 84 % | 73,127 mWh |
| 2022-06-1800:48:17 | Suspended |  | 87 % | 75,286 mWh |
| 00:49:51 | Active | AC | 87 % | 75,833 mWh |
| 02:19:00 | Suspended |  | 100 % | 86,974 mWh |
| 02:22:02 | Active | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:52:02 | Connected standby | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:52:03 | Active | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:52:33 | Connected standby | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:53:33 | Active | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:54:04 | Connected standby | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 02:57:17 | Active | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |
| 03:02:44 | Connected standby | AC | 100 % | 92,325 mWh |

The laptop is a GS76 Stealth 11UH running on Microsoft Windows 10.

---

Full report:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a feature in modern laptops that allows the CPU to temporarily draw more power than the AC connection can supply, and if you activate that in the Bios, the behavior you see should happen:

- High load, CPU runs on full AC supply *plus* battery power
- Normal load, CPU runs on AC supply and battery gets recharged.

HP calls this "DC Power Boost", and it can be activated in the Bios, under 'Advanced Settings'. Other manufactures probably have other cool names for it.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to know!